# How far can climate change go while still having enough of a biosphere to maintain a breathable atmosphere?

Tags: biology, atmosphere, climate-change

I’m running a one-shot campaign and I want it to be in a future where climate change has continued unabated but not so far that people can’t breathe on the surface.

Realistically, how hot can it get before oxygen production is reduced to the point where the air is no longer breathable?

Comment: Most, almost all, oxygen is produced by the plankton in the ocean. There is no way to get the ocean warmed up to 40 °C and still have people alive who would care. (And there is no way to get the ocean warmed up to 40 °C, at least not in the next two billion years. Unless a biggg asteroid hits us, but then it is over in an instant.)

Comment: It's not the temperature of the ocean that kills things, it's the acidity. As atmospheric CO2 concentration increases, so does the amount of CO2 being dissolved into carbonic acid. In fact, that's where _most_ of our CO2 goes. https://www.epa.gov/ocean-acidification/understanding-science-ocean-and-coastal-acidification

Comment: Plankton have a fast life cycle, they'll be able to evolve.  What will crash the system is when CO2 levels drop too low.

Comment: Just to make an unpopular point: I've been listening to "experts" claiming climate change of one form or another would lead to irreversible ecological damage of one form or another "in the next 5-10 years" since the 70s. They've yet to be right. My point? The only realistic answer is "we don't know." Life has proven remarkably resilient. We have some ideas, but no assurance. If what you're looking to do is *rationalize* an imaginative idea, then a good question is, "what do we think would lead to...."

Comment: What you're talking about is a catastrophic ecosphere collapse making the entire planet uninhabitable to all life which would be something else entirely by an order of magnitudes to any climate change model claimed or predicted to date by any serious scientist outside of the pulpiest of pulp fiction masquerading as sci-fi .. so you may need different words than 'climate change' to indicate your primary cause here?

Comment: @LorenPechtel which it won't of course if the plankton is fine, which is presumably your point? 

Comment: @JBH which would then be closed as opinion based, so asking this way is probably better 

Comment: @Pelinore CO2 is expected to drop as the sun gets warmer, eventually it will drop too low for most plants and most species will die.  That's probably your survival limit.

Comment: Climate change is one of the most researched topics in all of science. There really isn't much left to opinion. The statements that we'd hit an irreversible tipping point weren't wrong. We're losing more than 50,000 species a year right now. You don't get more irreversible than that. The only question is whether we can stop our self-destructive behavior before we get added to the list. I'll take on all contrary opinions if you need details, but this isn't the place for it.

Comment: @LorenPechtel causative mechanism and / or reference to data sets that show the asserted trend are always appreciated alongside claims on this topic, as bold faced lies have simply become so ubiquitous on this subject that I'd never just accept anyone's word from either side for anything about it any more 

Comment: @Pelinore Comments are too short for decent instruction. Our sweet spot is "I have situation X and would like consequence Y. I've tried A, B, and C, but they didn't work because of Z. Are there any Real World examples of Y that I can use to model my world?" Unfortunately, it's pretty rare to find questions asked that way.

Comment: It is not lack of oxygen that will kill us. Even not the concentration of CO2. Before that the temperature will be to high to walk outside. And probably before that agriculture will collapse because the ecosystem around us collapses. The amount of species that we are loosing is not relevant for our survival, except maybe honey bees and others that fulfill a critical role in the ecosystem relevant for agriculture. Nature usually finds a way to deal and recover. The specialist species die out and the generalist adapt and survive.

Comment: If you want to read a good story about that kind of future, Paolo Bacigalupi's "The Windup Girl" has some excellent worldbuilding in that direction.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with climate change isn't actually the temperature, it's the speed of the change. The difference between a quarter stick of dynamite and a charcoal briquette is time. What's safe to burn over half an hour will blow your grill apart if released in a tenth of a second.

The planet can adapt to change over millions of years. Extinction events are quick, but they still make watching the hands of a clock move look like a dogfight. The "Great Dying", the P-T extinction, wiped out 80% of aquatic species, 70% of terrestrial chordata (that's us) species, and the vast majority of all biomass on the planet. It occurred because our CO2 levels went from around 200ppm to around 2000ppm over a period of 60 thousand years.

We're on track to hit 2000 ppm in a mere 300 years. We are currently destroying species about 2000 times faster than natural selection can spit them out. Those who are watching the hands of the clock call it the "Holocene Extinction Event," and it's going on all around us.

The ocean PH is currently around 8.1, down .1 since the beginning of the industrial revolution. It's really surprising how little PH difference it takes to break biochemical processes. For instance, going from PH 7.5 to 7.4 is enough to change the ionization state of histidine, one of our essential amino acids. Ocean acidification is already responsible for significant coral bleaching. We aren't going to die because it's too hot, we're going to die because the entire ecosystem collapses out from underneath us.

Comment: Any "scientist" that is predicting climate 300 years from now is a sensationalistic, populistic fear-monger... Climate models are extremely inaccurate in predicting events even a few decades in advance (remember the predicted ice-age that predated the global warming?). Also, 2000 ppm of CO2? Without massive volcanic eruptions that is practically impossible. There probably isn't enough fosil fuel left to reach that number at all...

Comment: @Negdo: The main problem with making predictions over three centuries is that the one thing we are sure of is that *technology will change*. The stone age did not end for lack of stone. The bronze age did not end for lack of tin and copper. The steam age did not end for lack of coal and water. They ended because new technology emerged and took over. Three hundred years ago it was 1723, Louis XV was King of France, and the United Kingdom of Great Britain was 17 years old. Watt's steam engine was still 40 years in the future. We have *no idea* what technology will emerge in the next 300 years.

Comment: @AlexP I hate to be a pedant, but the bronze age literally ended because of a collapse of global trade meaning tin and copper were not in the same hands anymore. Bronze was generally seen as superior to iron at the time due to being much easier to work with. In fact, many bronze age civilisations had the ability to work iron, they just rarely used it, as it wasn't worth the effort when bronze was right there. So in a sense, the bronze age explicitly ended due to the lack of tin or copper (depending on area).

Comment: @Negdo, you're thinking of weather, not climate, and you missed the "it's not the heat, it's the speed" bit. Weather is unpredictable. Climate is inevitable. If you aren't familiar with the models, then you probably think that it's complex on the scale of ecology, but in reality it's no more complex than accounting. (that said, don't underestimate the complexity of accounting).

Comment: @RobertRapplean Complex or not, they are extremely inaccurate even a few years in advance. Their ability to predict the future events is so bad they would be mocked in other branches of science... The whole thing is more like religion than science. A whole lot of doomsday predictions and not much actual evidence or usable models. And climate is not inevitable. We had a miniature ice-age even a few centuries ago...

Comment: @AlexP, That 300 years started at the beginning of the industrial revolution, and we're about halfway through it. The entire climate change battle is about fighting people with massive wealth who don't want technology to change. If we can make tech change to eliminate emissions, we're golden.

Comment: @Negdo, Please cite your information sources. I'll cite mine. Let's start with climate.nasa.gov. They aren't the best, but they're good at bringing it down to the average person's level. Climate models are accurate to around .05 degrees per year, and even the most conservative ones trend up. Any complaint you can come up with, I guarantee a climatologist has heard it and addressed it.

Comment: @RobertRapplean The small difficulty with citing sources regarding "climate change" is that we have been in a situation for years where anyone researching anything but to explicitly support the prevailing narrative cannot get funding.  If you only pay for science that agrees with you, strangely, that's all you get.

Comment: @Jedediah, That's a blatant falsehood. Scientists are constantly trying to disprove their own theories. That's the foundation of science. For instance, they sent a satellite up to measure the amount of heat being received from the sun, and the amount reflected by the atmosphere, simply because that was a possible way to disprove climate change. Spoiler: it didn't. If you want change your statement to "every experiment performed recently gave results that support climate change," then you'd be much closer to the truth.

Answer (score 1):

The concept you need is called [wet-bulb temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet-bulb_temperature), essentially the temperature you get when you put a wet piece of cloth on your thermometer. If this goes above 35°C humans can't survive without artificial cooling. As I understand it, any other warm blooded animal would have the same problem.

So what you want is some tropical regions where this temperature is surpassed on a regular basis. It is too hot there for humans to live or even go there exploring. Further away from the equator it is still unpleasantly hot but survivable. I think current models predict that this will start happening with around 5°C of global warning, if you use say 10°C you should get a thick strip of heat death around the equator with some barely survivable areas closer to the poles.

Answer (score 0):

Getting some mass dying on the way is likely, though at least some of plants and algae are going to not only make it, but thrive as their competition would be dead.

[Paleocene–Eocene Thermal Maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleocene%E2%80%93Eocene_Thermal_Maximum) is not even related to any mass dying, and we already talk about +6C and polar regions with temperate forests. CO2 concentration reached at most [0.1%](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/2014PA002650)

Based on project RHO realistically humans should be able to live with 1% CO2

[image]

I'd expect some non-linear extrapolation, but plausibly you should get some jungle planet. (heat maintained, so low temperature differences)

I'd say that weakest part would be humans having to live with temperatures above 40C, though with air conditioning (or mountains: -6C/1000m) it would be still possible. I'd suspect that quite a few algae are going to enjoy it.

Concerning organism adapting - we would need milenia of CO2 emissions, so civilization doing so, would be able to release some adapted GMOs.